# Can't bind virtual host to different port with httpd (CentOS)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf, vhosts

I have a VDS with CentOS and Apache. I'm using virtual-based hosts so I have domain 'my.domain' and few subdomains like 'sub1.my.domain', 'sub2.my.domain' etc. Each of them have it own config file in /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/.

I need to redirect all connections from sub1.my.domain:8080 to another.web.site:8080. So I've added this lines in .htaccess file at sub1.my.domain's root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule (.*) http://another.web.site:8080
```

But it wouldn't work because web-server listen only to port 80. So I did modified /etc/httpd/httpd.conf this way:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

And did modified sub1.my.domain's vhost file. Instead of...

```
<VirtualHost myserverip:80>
    ServerName sub1.my.domain
    AddDefaultCharset off
    AssignUserID www-root www-root
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www-root/data/www/sub1.my.domain
...
</VirtualHost>
```

...it now contents

```
<VirtualHost myserverip:8080>
    ServerName sub1.my.domain
    AddDefaultCharset off
    AssignUserID www-root www-root
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www-root/data/www/sub1.my.domain
...
</VirtualHost>
```

So as described in [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#port) I've added new port to listen in httpd configuration and setup new port to resolve in domain's virtual host configuration. But when I'm trying to open sub1.my.domain:8080 I get an error - browser can't resolve that address. I've even forward 8080 port through iptables, reboot whole server but nothing helped.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Whole day spent to understand that fail2ban blocks all connections to 8080. I've added rule to fail2ban table through iptables and everything worked like a charm.